# How can you pass variables between cdk stacks without getting cross reference error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, clouddevelopmentkit

I need to pass INamespace to CloudMapOptions in order that the ECS tasks register to the AWS CloudMap, I get following error. I can't decouple them with CfnOutput, because I need the namespace in the ECS cloudMapOptions:

```
   Stack "users" cannot consume a cross reference from stack "servicediscovery". Cross stack references are only supported for stacks deployed to the same environment or between nested stacks and their parent stack.
```

I tried this : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-share-vpc-between-stacks, but without any success. How can I pass a variable of type INamespace between stacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error likely happens if you do one of the following:

1. You try to create a reference between stacks which are defined to live in 2 different regions

Note that such cross region [references are not supported](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/49#issuecomment-454800305)

2. You supply different [`StackProps`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.StackProps.html) as 3rd parameter to [`Stack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/stack.html) constructor

In order to resolve that please make sure to pass the same `env` value in `StackProps` e.g.

```
class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct){
    super(scope, "MyStack", {
      env: { 
        account: '123456789', 
        region: 'eu-central-1'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case the StackProps was not used but the properties had been destructured as separate parameters to the stack constructor. Putting them inside a proper StackProps object fixed the issue. The type of the properties was extended from StackProps.

Answer (score 7):

This "cross reference" error can also be caused by missing third argument to `super()`.

```
export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id); // Missing third argument
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue.

Comment: This happened to be the issue in my case as well. Seems to work without the third parameter for some stacks though...

Comment: Yeah. I think the issue happens when some constructs have a different "env" config to others.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe it was that simple!